# how to order a mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB collection called `foods`, like this:

```
[{ _id: ObjectId(), name: 'Pizza' },
{ _id: ObjectId(), name: 'Hamburguer' },
{ _id: ObjectId(), name: 'Coke' }]
```

2 apps (web and mobile) consume the same database and they allow the user to reorganize the list of foods (collection `foods`), for example:

```
[{ _id: ObjectId(), name: 'Coke' },
{ _id: ObjectId(), name: 'Pizza' },
{ _id: ObjectId(), name: 'Hamburguer' }]
```

the order made by the user must persist, if this information is accessed through another application, the `foods` collection must be ordered in a way that the user has previously chosen.

How do I do that? I'm using `nodejs`, `express` and `mongoose`, i don't know a method to update the entire collection.

Comment: MongoDB itself doesn't care how you query it. You can create a query document and persist it somewhere for the next use.

Comment: If this collection is specific to user then use another field and store in db which keeps the sort order(1,2,3)

Comment: Seeing that this is an array in the collection where order is maintained. You just need to pass an ordered array to store(whenver use changes/creates it).. and there onwards all retrievals would be ordered.